# Rigging Non-spherical eyes in 2.79 or 2.8 that will work in Unity

Tags: animation, rigging, unity

There used to be a trick to setting up non spherical eyes that can be squashed and stretched while still being able to use "track to" constraints to animate where the eyes look, it would also work in Unity when exported with the fbx format.

It seems like when the "track to" constraints are applied it breaks the effect. I remember this working in older versions of Blender like 2.76 possibly I don't quite remember which one. Is there an alternative method that can be used with 2.79 or even 2.8?

Would love know another technique as I tend to work with cartoony characters. Google hasn't yielded any useful info for me.
[image: non-spherical eye rig test]

Comment: Can you upload that file to [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and include it in your post?=

Comment: Sure, here ya go. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6194" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6194/)      Uh not sure why the link shows up like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate *eye rotate* and rename it to *TrackToBone*. Parent it to the parent of *eye scale*. (For this test setup, it won't need a parent.) Leave the track to constraint on *TrackToBone* as it was.

Add a **Copy Rotation** Constraint to the *eye rotate* with the *TrackToBone* the target. Choose **Local Space** for both inputs.

[image: local space constarint]

The *TrackToBone* will do the tracking and the *eye rotate* bone will copy it's rotation in the local (deformed) space.

Comment: Wow! thank you so much, this seems to be working. I also tried something with a "copy rotation" constraint but it didn't quite work out the way I set it up. Took your advice and added the "TrackToBone" exported as FBX and the rotation and scaling are animating as expected in Unity.